# How to expand options in a select in the same option/dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a select menu with a drop down list. But because there are a lot of choices I would like to show them categorized. Let's say I need people to select city. I would like countries and cities be an option, but if I select a country then the options expands in the cities of the selected country. 
Generally in html I can easily do but in the form it is a little bit tricky..

Here is my **html code:**

```
<select class="" placeholder="Your Choice">
    <option value="Your Destination">Country1</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city1</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city2</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city3</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">Country2</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city1</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city2</option>
    <option value="Your Destination">city3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You will need to create custom control for this. Probably nested `accordion`.

Comment: Yes that, was my first thought, but unfortunately the <select> seems not to  work with anything else but <option>. I have tried making a list, making accordion. I have the code working somewhere in the page but the same code inner <select> doesn't work, that's way I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best implementation, but can be used as reference for start.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/93s498j9/)

#### Code

```js
function createCountries() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        html += "<div class='country'>Country " + i + "</div>";
        html += "<div class='cities'></div>";
    }
    $("#content").html(html)
}

function createCities() {
    $(".country").each(function (row) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        var html = "";
        console.log(random);
        if (random == 0) random = 5;

        for (var i = 0; i < random; i++) {
            html += "<div href='#' class='city'>City " + i + "</div>";
        }
        $(this).next().html(html);
    })
}

function createAccordions() {
    $("#content").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: 100                 // Hack to keep it closd default
    });
    $("#main").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        active: 100                 // Hack to keep it closd default
        
    });
}

function createHTML() {
    console.log($("#content").html())
    createCountries();
    createCities();
    createAccordions();
}

createHTML()
```

```css
.country {
    color:#333;
    font-size:16px;
}
.city {
    color:Blue;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
    <div>Main</div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man you are great, but as I said above, the problem is not the code but working inner <select> tag. Your code works great in the page but when I add the <select> nothing happens. Thank you any way... I am leaving this without an answer just in case some one knows any hack.

Comment: Thats ok. And reiterating, `select` will not cater your requirement. Try creating custom control.

Comment: Also why are you adding accordions inside `select`?